# How to generate "x" jQuery scripts with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might sound very strange and probably it is, so forgive me if I'm committing a bad mistake.
I have an unspecified number of `<input type='text'>`, generated at runtime and identified with a progress number id like `id='data1'`, `id='data2'`...I would like to have a jQuery script on every input. I thought to generate x scripts for x inputs but it doesn't work.

How could I do this?

```js
function addPreparations (nos, pietanze) {
  var numeroTotale = nos.value;
  var box = document.getElementById("box_righe");
  generateScripts(numeroTotale);
  if (numeroTotale == '') {
    box.innerHTML = '';
  }
  else {
    var righe = "<table class='table table-hover'>";
    righe += "<th class='text-center'>Pietanza</th><th class='text-center'>U. di Misura</th><th class='text-center'>Quantità</th><th class='text-center'>Cuoco</th><th class='text-center'>Data di Preparazione</th>";
    for (i = 1; i <= numeroTotale; i++) {
      righe = righe + "<tr><td><select name='pietanza"+i+"' class='form-control' onchange='showMU(this.value, \"p\", "+i+");'>";
      righe = righe + "<option value=''>Selezionare la pietanza "+i+"</option>";
      for (j=0; j<pietanze.length; j++) {
        righe = righe + "<option value='"+pietanze[j]+"'>"+pietanze[j]+"</option>";
      }
      righe = righe + "</select></td>";
      righe = righe + "<td align='center'><p id='umis"+i+"' class='h5'>- - -</p></td>";
      righe = righe + "<td><input type='number' placeholder='Inserire la quantità' name='quantita"+i+"' class='form-control'/></td>";
      righe = righe + "<td><input type='text' placeholder='Inserire il cuoco' name='cuoco"+i+"' class='form-control'/></td>";
      righe = righe + "<td><input type='text' placeholder='GGMMAAAA' id='data"+i+"' class='form-control' name='data"+i+"' /></td></tr>";
    }
    righe = righe + "</table>";

    righe = righe + "<input type='submit' name='storageConfirm' value='Conferma' class='btn btn-success'/>&nbsp&nbsp";
    righe = righe + "<input type='reset' value='Reimposta' class='btn btn-danger'/>";

    box.innerHTML = righe;
  }
}

function generateScripts (total) {
  for (i=1; i<=total; i++) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").on('keydown', '#data'+i, function(e) {
        if ((e.keyCode == 8) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) || (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)) {
          return;
        }
        else {
          alert("Solo numeri!");
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you add a class to your inputs & use it as a selector?

Comment: I'll post my full code, so it will be more clear

Comment: in your jquery code, in the for loop, check if the '#data'+i exists, if not, exit the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use attribute selector `[]` with the start with `^` selector (`[id^="data"]`), your code should be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('keydown', '[id^="data"]', function(e) {
        //Your logic HERE
    });
});
```

Or you could give all your inputs a common class and use it as selector like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('keydown', '.common_class', function(e) {
        //Your logic HERE
    });
});
```

**NOTE :** It's better to use the `input` event when you track the user input, like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('input', '[id^="data"]', function(e) {
        //Your logic HERE
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why @Nomistake :) ?

Comment: @Zakaria dont remember  maybe: he's talking about '...  id like id='data1', id='data2'...' so my guess it has to be unique for an untold reason...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the loop here.  What you want to do is add a *class* to each of these elements.  Something like `inputdata`; make sure this same class is on all of the inputs.

Then you can just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.inputdata', function(e){
    });
});
```

Comment: he asks for id's

Comment: @Nomistake: True, but adding a class is still a valid solution.

Comment: Maybe. But he's talking about '...  id like id='data1', id='data2'...' so my guess it has to be unique for an untold reason...